# SQL Trigger that should update other table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to make a trigger that will update a table only if something is inserted in an other table

```
CREATE TABLE Purchases
(
PurchaseID INT IDENTITY NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
DateBought SMALLDATETIME,
Price MONEY CHECK (Price>0),
RealEstateID INT UNIQUE NOT NULL,
DealMadeByEmployeeID INT NOT NULL
);


INSERT INTO Purchases(DateBought, Price, RealEstateID, DealMadeByEmployeeID)
VALUES ('20161015 15:10:03','120000',3, 3); --Апартамент 170 квадратни метра

INSERT INTO Purchases(DateBought, Price, RealEstateID, DealMadeByEmployeeID)
VALUES ('20161219 13:13:30','200000',4, 3); --Къща 500 квадратни метра

INSERT INTO Purchases (Price,RealEstateID,DealMadeByEmployeeID)
VALUES ('130000',6,3); --непродаден апартамент

CREATE TABLE EmployeesSalary
(
EmployeeID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
CurrentSalary MONEY DEFAULT 0,-- на процент
MonthlySalesMade INT DEFAULT 0,
MonthlyRentsMade INT DEFAULT 0
);

INSERT INTO EmployeesSalary (EmployeeID, CurrentSalary)
VALUES (1, '400');

INSERT INTO EmployeesSalary (EmployeeID, CurrentSalary)
VALUES (2, '400');

INSERT INTO EmployeesSalary (EmployeeID, CurrentSalary)
VALUES (3, '400');

CREATE TRIGGER tr_EmployeesSalaryPurchasesUpdate --при INSERT в Purchases таблицата
ON Purchases
AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE EmployeesSalary
    SET EmployeesSalary.MonthlySalesMade=EmployeesSalary.MonthlySalesMade+1
    WHERE EmployeesSalary.EmployeeID IN (SELECT inserted.DealMadeByEmployeeID FROM inserted)
END
```

but based on the IDs.
My code doesn't get any errors but the trigger doesn't seem to work. What is my mistake?

https://postimg.org/image/rot0xcriv/

Comment: Please stop with the images. As I said in my last comment, I tried the code and it works. You are just not inserting the values in the **Purchases** table after creating the trigger

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It won't work if there are multiple updates unless NOCOUNT is SET to ON:

```
CREATE TRIGGER tr_EmployeesSalaryPurchasesUpdate 
ON Purchases
AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON -- new line of code
    UPDATE EmployeesSalary
    SET EmployeesSalary.MonthlySalesMade=EmployeesSalary.MonthlySalesMade+1
    WHERE EmployeesSalary.EmployeeID IN (SELECT inserted.DealMadeByEmployeeID FROM inserted)
END
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use an `INNER JOIN` there:

```
CREATE TRIGGER tr_EmployeesSalaryPurchasesUpdate --при INSERT в Purchases таблицата
ON Purchases
AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE ES 
    SET ES.MonthlySalesMade = ES.MonthlySalesMade+1
    FROM EmployeesSalary ES
    INNER JOIN INSERTED I
        ON ES.EmployeeID = I.DealMadeByEmployeeID;
END
```

Comment: @MitkoZ maybe you need the `ISNULL`, as in @M.Ali's answer

Comment: @MitkoZ what does "didn't work" means here?. What's the insert that you are trying?

Comment: well i am adding values in the purchases but the employeessalary isn't updating

Comment: which values?, that's important

Comment: i think the screenshot will make it clear what i want to happen

Comment: can't see the screenshot, but please just update your question with the values you are inserting after creating the trigger

Comment: @MitkoZ as I said, can't see the image. So please update your question instead. I'm not gonna continue answering your comments till the question is complete

Comment: ok.. so for example let's say i am inserting into Purchases     INSERT INTO Purchases(DateBought, Price, RealEstateID, DealMadeByEmployeeID)
VALUES ('20161015 15:10:03','120000',3, 3); --Апартамент 170 квадратни метра

Comment: same as the question values... and i want based on the DealMadeByEmployeeID to add a +1 in the EmployeesSalary to the corresponding Employee

Comment: What's so hard about **updating your question** with this information?. Also, are you inserting those values after the creation of the trigger?

Comment: Yes i am inserting it after the creation of the trigger

Comment: @MitkoZ well, since you are refusing to update your question I can't help you anymore. I tried the exact queries for creating your tables, then created the trigger as written in my answer, then inserted the values in the `Purchase` table (as in your question), and the results works just fine

Comment: just updated it... i would add the screenshot in the question but i don't have enough repu

Comment: @MitkoZ I can't keep answering you. I **tried** the trigger, it works. You must not be inserting the values in the `Purchases` table after creating the trigger

Comment: Oh i see... sorry my mistake... seems that the order was a little mixed up

Comment: @MitkoZ even after everyone asked if you were inserting the values after the trigger?

Comment: well i was using the "GO" statements to make them in different batches but it seems that something went wrong...

Comment: it seems that i was adding the Purchases values before the EmployeesSalary... i'm a newbie ..

Answer (score 0):

1. You can also use the `EXISTS` operator.
2. Also beaware of the possible NULLS in `MonthlySalesMade` column, `+1 update` will not work if there is a null values in that column.

---

```
CREATE TRIGGER tr_EmployeesSalaryPurchasesUpdate 
ON Purchases
AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE EmployeesSalary
    SET MonthlySalesMade = ISNULL(MonthlySalesMade, 0)+1
    WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                  FROM inserted
                  WHERE EmployeesSalary.EmployeeID = inserted.DealMadeByEmployeeID )
END
```

Comment: @MitkoZ what do you mean by `didn't work` ? what are you trying?

Comment: @MitkoZ in the picture you have added a row for EmpID 3 but your pointer is pointing to EmpID 1 in the EmpSalary Table. Also have you `inserted` after the trigger has been created? Also was it an insert or an update ?

Comment: @MitkoZ did you insert the data before you created the Trigger ?  If so delete the row and insert it again.

Comment: Oh i see... sorry my mistake... seems that the order was a little mixed up